# wordpress get_header() on a page template getting the head content inside of the body tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am having trouble with my Wordpress template page. When calling `get_header()` in the template page, the content of the `head` is appearing inside the `body` tag and causing trouble. I couldn't find a solution for this.

This is what I mean :

[page inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAuZH.png)

page template :

```html
<?php
  /*
  * Template Name: sub services
  */

  get_header();
?>

<h1>sub page</h1>

<?php
    get_footer();
?>
```

header.php :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
 <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
 <?php wp_title();?>
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lemonada:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/90928eb6b7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body id="theme-body" <?php body_class(); ?>>
  <header>
     <h1>Main Header</h1>
  </header>
```

and I have added a page in wordpress admin and linked it to the template.

[wordpress add page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3F4r.png)

Everything works fine except that the content of the head is in the body tag. when calling `get_header()`. In the `template.php`  I have checked my error log and its fine. I dont know what is causing this problem or what I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your `header.php` file contains the full `body` (including the *closing* `</body>`) and even the closing `</html>` tag. Your page template then appends to that some more HTML and a footer - that's invalid HTML and can't really be intended, is it?

Browser will probably try to fix those errors by adding missing or omitting superfluous tags, but in this case none of that will come up with the intended result - it will rather lead to a result like the one you are seeing.

The `header.php` file *can* contain the opening `<body>` tag, but not the closing `</body>`.  But it *should* contain the Wordpress loop, and inside that `the_content()` to load the actual page content, and also the other WP functions to fetch heading, featured image etc.

After that, you usually fetch the footer using `get_footer();`, which *might*  contain the closing `</body>` tag, if that's not in the page template.

So, the biggest problem in your code are the closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags and the resulting invalid HTML.

Comment: oh. i added the closing </body> nad </html> by mistake when inserting the code in the question, i acutally have it setup correctly in my actual code. the closings are in the footer. and i tried the the wordpress loop with the "the_content()" method but still with no luck. can you refer me to a source where i can see how to setup a custom template corctlly. btw im not using posts its custom code with php $_POST for sending and getting data. its working fine in the index.php page put not working in the template page.  thank you.